# Does Microsoft Edge support composite keypath in indexeddb

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, indexeddb

Below is sample snippet which will throw Data Error in Edge (v42.17134.1.0) but works fine in Chrome,

```
var request = indexedDB.open('test123', 1);
request.onupgradeneeded = () => {
    var db = request.result;
    var store = db.createObjectStore('store',{keyPath: ['col1', 
               'col2']});//composite keypath
};
request.onsuccess = (event) => {
    var db = event.target.result;
    var tx = db.transaction('store', 'readwrite');

    tx.objectStore('store').add({'col1': 1, 'col2':2});//Data Error
};
```

There is no issue if the keypath is not composite. Does the Legacy Edge browser support composite keypath?

Comment: Which version of Edge?  v80+ is Chromium-based.

Comment: I am using Microsoft Edge 42.17134.1.0

Comment: @JayBuckman - FWIW, it's v79+... :-) (But v80 is the current version.)

Comment: @user2021512 - That version of Edge is nearly two years out of date. Why that version, specifically?

Comment: It's likely OP hasn't installed any major Windows 10 updates, which are how Microsoft Edge versions typically get updated.

Comment: @user2021512 - You can download the new Edge from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge?form=MY01BL&OCID=MY01BL

Comment: Sometimes, we can't say the same thing(download new Edge) to end-user.

Answer (score 2):

I have tested it with MS Edge and able to produce the issue. It seems that the composite keypath not support the legacy version of Microsoft Edge or it is Edge default behavior. But it works well in the [New Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge) and [Microsoft Edge (chromium) version](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download), because they are chromium based. I will try to submit the feedback regarding this issue. If I get any response, I will try to provide you in the future. Thanks for your understanding

As a workaround, if you want to use composite keypath, I suggest you could try to upgrade the Microsoft Edge and use the [New Microsoft Edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge) or [Microsoft Edge (chromium) version](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download).